# Order of textview and imageview causing crash for unknown reason

Tags: android

I have an imageview and I want text on top of it. So in the relative layout I put the textview after the imageview and it's on top no problem. But when I test the app on my device, it crashes when trying to change the text.

```
myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentText);
myText.setText(percentage+"%");
```

The strange thing is when I simply change the order, put the textview first then the imageview, it doesn't crash. but the text is behind the image and can't be seen. Anyone know why this might be causing me trouble?

Comment: Can you add here logcat? we need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This using FrameLayout like this..

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/popup_addphoto" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgaddcontAddphoto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/addphoto"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtphoto"
                style="@style/txt_sign_up"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="@string/addphoto" />
        </FrameLayout>
```